# Django | Inter a valid date - Error en el formulario al selecionar una fecha

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms

Al seleccionar una fecha y darle a guardar devuelve error el input de la fecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Forms.py:

```
self.fields['datetime_incidence'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control','id':'datepicker'})
```

Models.py:

```
datetime_incidence = models.DateField ('FechaIncidencia',null=True, blank=True)
```

Template:

```
<script>
 $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
 closeText: 'Cerrar',
 prevText: '< Ant',
 nextText: 'Sig >',
 currentText: 'Hoy',
 monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
 monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
 dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
 dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
 dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
 weekHeader: 'Sm',
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 firstDay: 1,
 isRTL: false,
 showMonthAfterYear: false,
 yearSuffix: ''
 };
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
$(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto django acepta estos formatos ([Aquí puedes ver mas información](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)):

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
    '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
    '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
    '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
]
```

Si quieres que te acepte un formato diferente, en tu settings.py tienes que indicarlo asi para que aplique de manera global:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%d/%m/%Y',  # '21/03/2014'
)
```